# Unity c# rooms finding close rooms

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have a Unity game I'm working on. Currently it’s at a basic state, but the goal is to somewhat replicate the gameplay of old style telnet MUDs in a graphical fashion. Map construction at this phase is manual, not automatic, although that’s planned for later. I can easily place the rooms in a 2-d grid, each a number of whole units away from each other, on the x and y axis.
I’m at the stage where I’ve got several  “Room” gameObjects, and they each have a C# script (let’s call the script “a_room.cs”). Each script has a public gameObject variable for the rooms that are north, south, east, and west of that particular “room”.

My question; is there a way to have each and every “room”, either at runtime or in-editor, figure on its own out which “rooms” are closest to each of its particular cardinal direction? Taking into account that there may be several rooms in a given direction and only the closest is desired, as well as the fact that there may be NO rooms in that direction?

I don't necessarily need code as an answer, the logic and important functions are what I'm after.

Also; if there’s something blatantly wrong with this method of thought alternative suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You could tag each of your rooms with an arbitrary tag (let's say "room" for now) and then use [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) to get a list of all rooms and then from there it's simple math to find the closest room in each direction.

Comment: Thanks Taelsin, I'm going to use that along with the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a global list containing all these a_room objects.

Ideally, you can make the N/S/E/W assignments while instantiating the rooms itself. Ex:  After R1 is created, R2 is created to the East of R1 and also assigned as the EastRoom of R1.

Otherwise, since the rooms are placed at a certain 'n' units away from the next one (horizontally or vertically), you can search the list to see what rooms are placed at the neighbouring locations to a certain room.
Ex: If R1 is known to be at position (x,y), search through the global list to find a room whose location is (x+n, y) and assign that as the EastRoom of R1; the room at (x-n, y) as the WestRoom of R1, etc.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If the game objects are already crated, then you can order them in a list by its position(x,y,z) once they are ordered just set the N,S,E,O to the next object in the list...